# What are the warning signs that a MySQL table might be corrupted

Tags: mysql, corruption

For some reason, it's not the first thing I think of when diagnosing very strange table errors.  I had an issue when doing an `order by` I'd wind up with only one record.  `Explain` said I should have 28 rows, if I take out the `order by` I have 28 rows.  Well, the problem was table corruption, but unlike some errors where MySQL goes right out and tells you your table is corrupt, I didn't know until I checked it.

I was just wondering if there is a list, or we could make a list of all the times when a MySQL database is corrupted, but you might not necessarily know it is.

Answer (score 1):

Run [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html) on the table.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. I was just wondering if there was a list of warning signs that might give me an indication that I need to run check table

Comment: Many people monitor the log results of mysqlcheck regularly (daily, weekly, monthly) as a part of database maintenance. It frees space, optimizes indexes, and is proactive against corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Fatal errors when trying to read/write to a table is the evidence in most of the cases I've run into.

Also, `EXPLAIN` only provides an estimated number of rows, so I wouldn't necessarily consider an `EXPLAIN` output with an unexpected number of rows read/returned as an indication of table corruption.